# C++ - Popping the first element of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, erase, binary-heap

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I promise I tried to find an answer first.

I want to make a binary heap using a vector. To do so, I have to implement a pop function, that removes the "top." In this case, it simply removed the first element.

I tried using a move function, as such:

```
items[Root()] = std::move(items[cur_size--]);
```

This should swap the root with another element, which it would then reorder (which also hasn't been working).

Instead, I tried something this:

```
std::vector<int> items;
int root = 0;
size_t Root() {
  return root;
}

void Pop() {
  items.erase(items.begin()+root);
  root++;
  // here I would call the reorder function
}
```

In this way I would effectively change the root and operate as if the vector started on the n-th position, rather than at 0.

My question is, does that make sense, or is there a better way I could be implementing this?

edit: added vector

Comment: Why not increasing/decreasing an index instead of moving all the data?

Comment: @Jose that's what I'm doing in the second part, moving the root index and erasing the original root

Comment: The fragments are a bit small to really understand your problem with the first code. Are you sure you mean `[cur_size--]`? Often with array/vector code, cur_size indicates the element after the end of the array, so the index is wrong before the decriment, so you might mean `[--cur_size]`

Comment: @GemTaylor that solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To pop the first element of an `std::vector` (lets call it `myvector`), you just have to write:

```
myvector.erase(myvector.begin()); // pop front
```

---

Now if you have a binary tree stored into a `std::vector`, removing the root will leave you with the two childs (two roots).

If you want to keep only one of the two sub-trees, you need to select the one you want (the new root).
Then, depending whether your `std::vector` stores the binary tree in ***breadth-first*** or in ***depth-first***, you have to search all the elements relative to the sub-tree you want to keep ([Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)) and build another `std::vector` with the desired sub-tree.
In the end, you assign the computed sub-tree to the original vector.

---

I hope this will help you.